# Factory Girl override field defined on after(:build)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I can have multiple profiles. All of the have to be associated with the same "api license".
Here is my profile factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :profile do
    name "MyString"

    after(:build) do |profile|
      api_license = ApiLicense.find_by_name('API test name')
      api_license ||= FactoryGirl.create(:api_license)

      profile.api_license = api_license
    end
  end
end
```

I can define multiple profiles with FactoryGirl.build(:profile) or FactoryGirl.create(:profile) and all of them are attached to the same api license, which is good.

The problem comes when I want to test the "no api license case".

For example FactoryGirl.build(:profile, :api_license=>nil) doesn´t work because it seems that after(:build) is executed after assigning nil value to api license.

Any ideas about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another factory without assigning api license

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :profile_without_api_license, :class => Profile do
    name "MyString"
  end

  factory :profile do
    name "MyString"

    after(:build) do |profile|
      api_license = ApiLicense.find_by_name('API test name')
      api_license ||= FactoryGirl.create(:api_license)

      profile.api_license = api_license
    end
  end
end
```

Call the factory `profile_without_api_license` whenever you want one without license